# Social Login buttons are not working in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, social-networking

In my app I have to load a web URL [Link](http://academy.careerpillar.com/#/login) in UIWebView where user can login with social login (i.e FB, Google, Linkedin). The problem is that when user clicks login user is not navigating to that social login page.

If we past directly load the social login page it's working fine with UIWebView.

Is there any settings for UIWebView ?

Here is the code in viewDidLoad Method, after this URL there is social login links but it's not invoking any social login page.

```
    NSString *urlString = @"http://academy.careerpillar.com/#/login";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: Can you include the code that's resulting in this described behaviour?

Comment: @jehana1 - Please check above code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when user clicks on any social media sites, they open in pop-up so in uiwebview they open in another tab which doesn't load naturally. Do one thing, change your "http://academy.careerpillar.com/#/login" page and open the social sites within parent or self i.e.

```
<a href="ur link" target="_parent">dummy content</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="ur link" target="_self">dummy content</a>
```